# Problems with dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Why the date appears like 1900-01-01 in the table (SQL Server 2014)?

I insert date 10-10-2016, but when I list the table (`select * from table1`) the date appears like 1900-01-01...

Comment: What's your actual `insert` statement?

Comment: .. and column definition, and locale.

Comment: You really haven't given us enough to work with, but you should be aware that 1900-01-01 is the [default value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) for a `datetime` data type. My guess is you think you're inserting a different date but something is screwed up in your insert statement leading to the default value being inserted instead.

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the date inside single quotes.  If you insert a blank date, then it gets translated to `'1900-01-01'`. You should also be using a deterministic format - like `'YYYYMMDD'` - when translating strings to dates/datetimes and back.

Lets try to insert 11th of October 2016, using various ways:

```
create table #testing
( datecolumn1 date,
  datecolumn2 date,
  datecolumn3 date,
  datecolumn4 datetime
);

insert into #testing
  (datecolumn1, datecolumn2, datecolumn3, datecolumn4)
values 
  ('20161011',     -- good, deterministic format
   '11-10-2016',   -- bad, non-deterministic. May work or not
    '',            -- empty string, translates to "0th date": 1900-01-01
   11-10-2016      -- guess what happens here!
  );

select convert(varchar(11), datecolumn1, 106) as datecolumn1,
       convert(varchar(11), datecolumn2, 106) as datecolumn2,
       convert(varchar(11), datecolumn3, 106) as datecolumn3,
       convert(varchar(11), datecolumn4, 106) as datecolumn4
from #testing;

drop table #testing;
```

Result:

```
datecolumn1   datecolumn2   datecolumn3   datecolumn4
11 Oct 2016   10 Nov 2016   01 Jan 1900   26 Jun 1894
```

Tested at **[rextester.com](http://rextester.com/PGX51457)**.